# Boost asio io service memcpy()

Tags: boost-asio, boost-thread

I have build application based on boost::asio. Sometimes I got this kind of core dump (not regullary). I tried investigate what's going on but I haven't more ideas to solve it.
In my point of view I think that could be some problem inside io service object - I mean maybe any bug? Should I update it ?
Anybody can explain what does memcpy() do in this case ? What is a reason of core ?

More details:
Platform . SunOS.
Boost - 1.49

```
/app/bin/executor_3'executor_dumpstack+0x13 [0x426645]
/app/bin/executor_3'signal_dumpstack+0x9d [0x426625]
/lib/amd64/libc.so.1'__sighndlr+0x6 [0xfffffd7fff224ea6]
/lib/amd64/libc.so.1'call_user_handler+0x2a4 [0xfffffd7fff217b5c]
/lib/amd64/libc.so.1'memcpy+0x1929 [0xfffffd7fff18a449] [Signal 11 (SEGV)]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZNK5boost4_mfi3mf2Iv3GETRKNS_6system10error_codeEmE4callINS_10shared_ptrIS2_EES5_mEEvRT_PKvRT0_RT1_+0x8b [0xfffffd7ff64ff869]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZNK5boost4_mfi3mf2Iv3GETRKNS_6system10error_codeEmEclINS_10shared_ptrIS2_EEEEvRT_S6_m+0x3c [0xfffffd7ff64fe47e]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN5boost3_bi5list3INS0_5valueINS_10shared_ptrI3GETEEEEPFNS_3argILi1EEEvEPFNS7_ILi2EEEvEEclINS_4_mfi3mf2IvS4_RKNS_6system10error_codeEmEENS0_5list2ISL_RKmEEEEvNS0_4typeIvEERT_RT0_i+0x72 [0xfffffd7ff64fce58]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN5boost3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf2Iv3GETRKNS_6system10error_codeEmEENS0_5list3INS0_5valueINS_10shared_ptrIS4_EEEEPFNS_3argILi1EEEvEPFNSF_ILi2EEEvEEEEclIS6_mEEvRKT_RKT0_+0x43 [0xfffffd7ff64fbfa7]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN5boost4asio6detail17read_streambuf_opINS0_19basic_stream_socketINS0_2ip3tcpENS0_21stream_socket_serviceIS5_EEEESaIcENS1_18transfer_exactly_tENS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf2Iv3GETRKNS_6system10error_codeEmEENSB_5list3INSB_5valueINS_10shared_ptrISF_EEEEPFNS_3argILi1EEEvEPFNSQ_ILi2EEEvEEEEEEclESJ_mi+0x16f [0xfffffd7ff64fa31b]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN5boost4asio6detail7binder2INS1_17read_streambuf_opINS0_19basic_stream_socketINS0_2ip3tcpENS0_21stream_socket_serviceIS6_EEEESaIcENS1_18transfer_exactly_tENS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf2Iv3GETRKNS_6system10error_codeEmEENSC_5list3INSC_5valueINS_10shared_ptrISG_EEEEPFNS_3argILi1EEEvEPFNSR_ILi2EEEvEEEEEEESI_mEclEv+0x2d [0xfffffd7ff6503345]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN5boost4asio19asio_handler_invokeINS0_6detail7binder2INS2_17read_streambuf_opINS0_19basic_stream_socketINS0_2ip3tcpENS0_21stream_socket_serviceIS7_EEEESaIcENS2_18transfer_exactly_tENS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf2Iv3GETRKNS_6system10error_codeEmEENSD_5list3INSD_5valueINS_10shared_ptrISH_EEEEPFNS_3argILi1EEEvEPFNSS_ILi2EEEvEEEEEEESJ_mEEEEvT_z+0x8e [0xfffffd7ff6502d76]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN33boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers6invokeIN5boost4asio6detail7binder2INS3_17read_streambuf_opINS2_19basic_stream_socketINS2_2ip3tcpENS2_21stream_socket_serviceIS8_EEEESaIcENS3_18transfer_exactly_tENS1_3_bi6bind_tIvNS1_4_mfi3mf2Iv3GETRKNS1_6system10error_codeEmEENSE_5list3INSE_5valueINS1_10shared_ptrISI_EEEEPFNS1_3argILi1EEEvEPFNST_ILi2EEEvEEEEEEESK_mEES11_EEvRT_RT0_+0x3e [0xfffffd7ff650250a]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN5boost4asio6detail19asio_handler_invokeINS1_7binder2INS1_17read_streambuf_opINS0_19basic_stream_socketINS0_2ip3tcpENS0_21stream_socket_serviceIS7_EEEESaIcENS1_18transfer_exactly_tENS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf2Iv3GETRKNS_6system10error_codeEmEENSD_5list3INSD_5valueINS_10shared_ptrISH_EEEEPFNS_3argILi1EEEvEPFNSS_ILi2EEEvEEEEEEESJ_mEESA_SB_SC_S10_EEvRT_PNS4_IT0_T1_T2_T3_EE+0x21 [0xfffffd7ff6501f61]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN33boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers6invokeIN5boost4asio6detail7binder2INS3_17read_streambuf_opINS2_19basic_stream_socketINS2_2ip3tcpENS2_21stream_socket_serviceIS8_EEEESaIcENS3_18transfer_exactly_tENS1_3_bi6bind_tIvNS1_4_mfi3mf2Iv3GETRKNS1_6system10error_codeEmEENSE_5list3INSE_5valueINS1_10shared_ptrISI_EEEEPFNS1_3argILi1EEEvEPFNST_ILi2EEEvEEEEEEESK_mEES12_EEvRT_RT0_+0x25 [0xfffffd7ff65019a3]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN5boost4asio6detail23reactive_socket_recv_opINS0_17mutable_buffers_1ENS1_17read_streambuf_opINS0_19basic_stream_socketINS0_2ip3tcpENS0_21stream_socket_serviceIS7_EEEESaIcENS1_18transfer_exactly_tENS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf2Iv3GETRKNS_6system10error_codeEmEENSD_5list3INSD_5valueINS_10shared_ptrISH_EEEEPFNS_3argILi1EEEvEPFNSS_ILi2EEEvEEEEEEEE11do_completeEPNS1_15task_io_serviceEPNS1_25task_io_service_operationESL_m+0xc4 [0xfffffd7ff65007cc]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN5boost4asio6detail25task_io_service_operation8completeERNS1_15task_io_serviceERKNS_6system10error_codeEm+0x32 [0xfffffd7ff6433dc8]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN5boost4asio6detail15task_io_service10do_run_oneERNS1_11scoped_lockINS1_11posix_mutexEEERNS2_11thread_infoERNS1_8op_queueINS1_25task_io_service_operationEEERKNS_6system10error_codeE+0x202 [0xfffffd7ff6433c9e]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN5boost4asio6detail15task_io_service3runERNS_6system10error_codeE+0xff [0xfffffd7ff6433925]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN5boost4asio10io_service3runEv+0x26 [0xfffffd7ff64335d6]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN6ZohaIO9RunIOEv+0x19 [0xfffffd7ff64335ad]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZNK5boost4_mfi3mf0Iv6ZohaIOEclEPS2_+0x64 [0xfffffd7ff6440cee]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN5boost3_bi5list1INS0_5valueIP6ZohaIOEEEclINS_4_mfi3mf0IvS3_EENS0_5list0EEEvNS0_4typeIvEERT_RT0_i+0x41 [0xfffffd7ff6440c4d]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN5boost3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf0Iv6ZohaIOEENS0_5list1INS0_5valueIPS4_EEEEEclEv+0x33 [0xfffffd7ff6440bfb]
/opt/lib/extralibs/exe_io.so'_ZN5boost6detail11thread_dataINS_3_bi6bind_tIvNS_4_mfi3mf0Iv6ZohaIOEENS2_5list1INS2_5valueIPS6_EEEEEEE3runEv+0x1c [0xfffffd7ff6440514]
/opt/csw/gxx/lib/amd64/libboost_thread.so.1.49.0'0xf655 [0xfffffd7ffa97f655]
/lib/amd64/libc.so.1'_thrp_setup+0xbc [0xfffffd7fff224b14]
/lib/amd64/libc.so.1'_lwp_start+0x0 [0xfffffd7fff224de0]
```

objdump output.

```
0000000000000000 <_ZNK5boost4_mfi3mf2Iv3GETRKNS_6system10error_codeEmE4callINS_10shared_ptrIS2_EES5_mEEvRT_PKvRT0_RT1_>:
    template<class U, class B1, class B2> R call(U & u, T const *, B1 & b1, B2 & b2) const
    {
        BOOST_MEM_FN_RETURN (u.*f_)(b1, b2);
    }

    template<class U, class B1, class B2> R call(U & u, void const *, B1 & b1, B2 & b2) const
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   53                      push   %rbx
   5:   48 83 ec 38             sub    $0x38,%rsp
   9:   48 89 7d e8             mov    %rdi,-0x18(%rbp)
   d:   48 89 75 e0             mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
  11:   48 89 55 d8             mov    %rdx,-0x28(%rbp)
  15:   48 89 4d d0             mov    %rcx,-0x30(%rbp)
  19:   4c 89 45 c8             mov    %r8,-0x38(%rbp)
    {
        BOOST_MEM_FN_RETURN (get_pointer(u)->*f_)(b1, b2);
  1d:   48 8b 45 e0             mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
  21:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  24:   e8 00 00 00 00          callq  29 <_ZNK5boost4_mfi3mf2Iv3GETRKNS_6system10error_codeEmE4callINS_10shared_ptrIS2_EES5_mEEvRT_PKvRT0_RT1_+0x29>
  29:   48 89 c2                mov    %rax,%rdx
  2c:   48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
  30:   48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
  33:   83 e0 01                and    $0x1,%eax
  36:   84 c0                   test   %al,%al
  38:   74 23                   je     5d <_ZNK5boost4_mfi3mf2Iv3GETRKNS_6system10error_codeEmE4callINS_10shared_ptrIS2_EES5_mEEvRT_PKvRT0_RT1_+0x5d>
  3a:   48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
  3e:   48 8b 40 08             mov    0x8(%rax),%rax
  42:   48 8d 04 02             lea    (%rdx,%rax,1),%rax
  46:   48 8b 08                mov    (%rax),%rcx
  49:   48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
  4d:   48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
  50:   48 83 e8 01             sub    $0x1,%rax
  54:   48 8d 04 01             lea    (%rcx,%rax,1),%rax
  58:   48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
  5b:   eb 07                   jmp    64 <_ZNK5boost4_mfi3mf2Iv3GETRKNS_6system10error_codeEmE4callINS_10shared_ptrIS2_EES5_mEEvRT_PKvRT0_RT1_+0x64>
  5d:   48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
  61:   48 8b 00                mov    (%rax),%rax
  64:   48 8b 4d c8             mov    -0x38(%rbp),%rcx
  68:   48 8b 19                mov    (%rcx),%rbx
  6b:   48 8b 4d e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rcx
  6f:   48 8b 49 08             mov    0x8(%rcx),%rcx
  73:   48 8d 3c 0a             lea    (%rdx,%rcx,1),%rdi
  77:   48 8b 4d d0             mov    -0x30(%rbp),%rcx
  7b:   48 89 da                mov    %rbx,%rdx
  7e:   48 89 ce                mov    %rcx,%rsi
```

Comment: As @PSIAlt mentioned, the crash is in your completion handler: `bind` attempts to invoke a member-function of an object that was already destroyed. Advice: stick with `shared_from_this` idiom, do not bind completion handlers to raw `this` pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: use **c++filt** utility so your backtrace will become readable: `cat backtrace | c++filt`

Something happen to **async_read** handler on GET invoking. Maybe this object is destroyed at the time handler is invoked, or some mess with parameters. Cant say accurately without code, but something with read callback is what can be seen from this backtrace.